# Follow artists with Spotify SDK

Tags: spotify, libspotify, spotify-app

I want to write a little Deezer to Spotify switcher, which transfers my artists and albums to my Spotify account. How can I follow an artist and add an album to my music library using one of Spotify's SDK (Libspotify, Web-API or Android SDK)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an awesome feature! (As long as it's not the other way around ;-)

Following and unfollowing artists and users isn't possible **just yet**, but please stay tuned for updates. You can either follow [@SpotifyPlatform](http://twitter.com/spotifyplatform) on Twitter or follow the [Web API Change log](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/change-log/). I can also update this answer once this feature is available.

**Update: Following artists or users is possible to do using the [Follow Artists or Users endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/follow-artists-users/) in the Web API. It was released in December, 2014.**